# Builds the map only when the GoogleApiClient is successfully connected?

Tags: android, google-maps, geolocation, google-maps-markers, google-maps-android-api-2

I'm developing an Android app for exercise, to better understand the Google maps api . In this apps i want to show some marker and if Android knows the user's current position I want to show It on the maps. Following the google tutorial I do it. But I have a doubt on the better way to get the maps and make the Google Api Client connection. In the tutorial https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/current-places-tutorial the developer builds the map only when the Google Api Client is successfully connected. Is It correct to do in this way in my study case ? In my case the important thing is to show some markers position on the maps and only if is It possible also show the current user position ?
In my mind i would have done in contrary way : before build maps and only in maps ready callback makes the GoogleApiClient connection. ( I think the Api client connection is needed only to get the current location position right ?)

In the tutorial they do in this way :

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        .....
        buildGoogleApiClient();
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        ....
    }
   /**
     * Builds a GoogleApiClient.
     * Uses the addApi() method to request the Google Places API and the Fused Location Provider.
     */
    private synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .enableAutoManage(this /* FragmentActivity */,
                        this /* OnConnectionFailedListener */)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .addApi(Places.GEO_DATA_API)
                .addApi(Places.PLACE_DETECTION_API)
                .build();
        createLocationRequest();
    }

 @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
        getDeviceLocation();
        // Build the map.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }

    */
    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {
        .... do stuff....}
```

I would have done in the following way :

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        .....
        buildGoogleApiClient();

         // Build the map.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

    }
   /**
     * Builds a GoogleApiClient.
     * Uses the addApi() method to request the Google Places API and the Fused Location Provider.
     */
    private synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .enableAutoManage(this /* FragmentActivity */,
                        this /* OnConnectionFailedListener */)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .addApi(Places.GEO_DATA_API)
                .addApi(Places.PLACE_DETECTION_API)
                .build();
        createLocationRequest();
    }

 @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
        getDeviceLocation();

    }

    */
    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {
         mGoogleApiClient.connect();
         ----do stuff....
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Only if the Google Play service connection has been enabled, the map would be loaded in the device, and you can't plot your markers if the map has not been loaded.Hence it is not possible to build maps without google play services.

Comment: Why in this tutorial https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/map-with-marker  the developer show the build the maps withoud makes a google play service connection (it doesn't do explict call to mGoogleApiClient.connect(); ) ?

Comment: In this tutorial developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/… the developer show the maps and adds markers withoud makes a google api client connection (it doesn't do explict call to mGoogleApiClient.connect(); ) . I suppose the appi client connection is only to get the location, or I supposed wrong ?
However I have edited the question in first post, maybe now is more clear :)

Comment: No your assumption is wrong, it is required for loading the map itself.

Comment: Why in some tutorial there isn't a googleapiclient connection ? For example in this code : https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/map-with-marker . Is not the api client always  necessary ?